# "stringWithContentsOfURL" returns empty data

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsxmlparser

i am working with web services these days ,and with all xml files that i am parsing things are fine ,but with the last one the famous method "stringWithContentsOfURL" returns empty data. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your URL references a non-existing file, or the content of the file can not be encoded as a NSString.

Comment: the content is not empty ,so i have doubt about encoding format

Comment: @dingua: Try using dataWithContentsofURL: If that will download, then it is most likely encoding problems.